# How to resolve the path to a file in a module via the Play router

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a set of SVG image files that are part of a Play module, shared by multiple Play apps. For older browsers that don't support SVG (*cough* IE6), I've written a controller that converts these to PNG format, based on the browser's user-agent string.

For this to work, I need to get access to the original SVG file. However, the file may be in the module's `/public/images` directory or the application's. The Play router is able to resolve either case seamlessly (i.e. a GET request to `/public/images/foo.svg` always works, whether the `foo.svg` file is in the application's `/public/images` directory or the application's `/public/images` directory). So I would like to leverage Play's router logic to find the file, get its absolute path, and feed it into the conversion library.

Is this possible? I tried some methods in Play's `Router` class, but they couldn't find the file. Perhaps there's a way to make a sort of internal GET request within the server through the normal routing logic, and receive the result as a byte stream?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: BTW isn't it also better to use one format (PNG) for each browser ?

Comment: The module I'm using contains SVGs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use play VirtualFile to do this

```
Play.getVirtualFile("public/images/foo.svg")
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it easier just to create ... separate folder in the filesystem for such files and upload them apart of the application?

In case of change you won't need to redeploy whole application and also you'll have a real path to the file in filesystem. BTW, that's good idea for other static (not requiring compiling) anyway in such you will need to use separate HTTP server at the frontend or write an action for serving the files to the browser (IMHO first option is faster)

Comment: The problem then is that I'd have to convert the SVGs every time a new one is added. The extreme majority of users have browsers with SVG support, so I don't want to add work every time a new image is added to the project. So the idea is to add on-the-fly conversion for IE6 users and never think about it again.